# How to call an API ASP.net with AJAX from a HTML page

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, api

I'm getting started with ASP.net API and I'm trying to call my API with AJAX from my HTML page. I just want to show a list of products and search by Id, but my get request doesn't seems work and the same for the search by Id request.

Here is my controller.

```
using ProductsApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ProductsApp.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[]
        {
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
        };

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
    }
}
```

My HTML page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Product App</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <h2>All Products</h2>
    <ul id="products" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Search by ID</h2>
    <input type="text" id="prodId" size="5" />
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="find();" />
    <p id="product" />
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var uri = 'api/products';

    $(document).ready(function () {
      // Send an AJAX request
      $.getJSON(uri)
          .done(function (data) {
            // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
            $.each(data, function (key, item) {
              // Add a list item for the product.
              $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#products'));
            });
          });
    });

    function formatItem(item) {
      return item.Name + ': $' + item.Price;
    }

    function find() {
      var id = $('#prodId').val();
      $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
          .done(function (data) {
            $('#product').text(formatItem(data));
          })
          .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            $('#product').text('Error: ' + err);
          });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, thank for your advices.

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't work`? Are you getting any error? Are you able to debug asp.net API code?

Comment: Try assigning the complete url of the API to `var uri`

Comment: by "it doesn't work" I mean that my "get all" request don't get the products and in my HTML page I can't see any product, I see just the title "All products" from HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Your URI variable is defined as "api/products", but you dont have a default GET for products. to call your api via ajax, your URI must have the method name you want to call, unless you are using a RESTfull API, which you aren't. The correct URI would be "api/products/GetAllProducts". You could also use [Route] property on on your controller and methods, to define custom routes for your API

Answer (score 0):

Your API controller endpoints are not in expected REST format. If my guess is correct, you will not be able to hit api/products endpoint even via browser.
api/products won't work unless you have custom routing configuration. Try changing your controller actions as Get, Get(int id)..etc.

```
using ProductsApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ProductsApp.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[]
        {
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
        };

        public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
    }
}
```